# Configuring CORS for a Team Foundation Server extension

Tags: tomcat, iis, cors

I'm building a hub extension for TFS that will reach out to an HP Fortify REST api and return a list of projects. The TFS server and Fortify server are both on-prem running in the same domain.

Fortify has a unique sort of configuration where IIS 8.5 is the front-end to Tomcat 8.

The first thing I'm trying to do is make a call from the TFS extension in order to obtain a token from Fortify. Full disclosure, I'm a javascript novice, so this might not be awesome:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "https://fortifyserver/ssc/api/v1/auth/obtain_token",
   data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Teambuild" }),
   contentType: "application/json",
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ********************");                    
   },
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   }
 });
```

When the above script executes, I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://fortifyserver/ssc/api/v1/auth/obtain_token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

I'm pretty sure this is CORS related, so the question I have is which piece of the Fortify configuration should be tweaked? IIS or Tomcat or both?

Comment: From a Fortify rep: It appears there is an existing enhancement request for CORS support and there 
is no target date on when it will be made available.

Comment: Given that new found knowledge, I'm going to look at proxying the CORS requests. If it works, I'll post the solution as my answer.

Comment: I've also learned that Fortify does not support jsonp, so my options are becoming very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an alternative way to do this. I created a custom service endpoint for the HP Fortify Rest API based on guidance from this series of [blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/14/service-endpoints-overview/) by Sriram Balasubramaniam.

I also used [jsonpath online evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/) to help figure out the correct result syntax for each data source in my custom extension. Here's an example of what the data source looks like for the endpoint:

```
 "dataSources": [                
                {
                    "name": "GetAllProjects",
                    "endpointUrl": "$(endpoint.url)api/v1/projects",
                    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.data.[*]"
                }
           ]
```

And here's an example of an ajax call to consume the endpoint:

```
var queryUri = baseUri + '/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpointproxy?endpointId=' + $connectionDropdown.val() + '&api-version=3.0-preview.1';                           
var projectQueryContent = '{"dataSourceDetails": {"dataSourceName":"GetAllProjects"}}';

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: queryUri,
                                data: projectQueryContent,
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                headers: { 'Authorization': basicAuthHeader }
                            })
                                .done(function (data) {
                                    $(data.result).each(function (i, e) {
                                    var el = JSON.parse(e);
                                    //console.log('Project Name: ' + el.name);
                                    $projectDropdown.append($('<option value="' + el.id + '">' + el.name + '</option>'));
                                    });                                            

                                });
```

Now I have a VSTS/TFS extension with a hub and custom endpoint.